# What does iron (III) get reduced to in a galvanic cell: solid iron or iron (II)?

Tags: electrochemistry

Recently, I built a galvanic cell in the lab with iron (III) nitrate, magnesium sulfate, and carbon and magnesium electrodes.

My question is:

> When the iron $3+$ ions are reduced, do they reduce to iron $2+$ ions or to solid iron?

I know the reduction potential for iron $3+$ to iron $2+$ is greater, indicating that it is more likely to occur.

Comment: Magnesium electrode? And what, non-aqueous solution?

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\ce {Fe^{2+} {(aq)} + 2e^{-} &<=> Fe {(s)}} &E^⦵= \pu{-0.44V}\\
\ce {Fe^{3+} {(aq)} + e^{-} &<=> Fe^{2+} {(aq)}} &E^⦵= \pu{+0.77V}\\
\ce {Mg^{2+} {(aq)} + 2e^{-} &<=> Mg {(s)}} &E^⦵= \pu{-2.37V}\\
\end{align}$$

Thus

$$
\begin{align}
\ce {Mg {(s)} + 2Fe^{3+} {(aq)} &<=> Mg^{2+} {(aq)} +2Fe^{2+} {(aq)}}&&E^⦵_{\text{cell}}= 0.77--2.37=\pu{+3.14V}\\
\ce {Mg {(s)} + Fe^{2+} {(aq)} &<=> Mg^{2+} {(aq)} +Fe {(s)}}&&E^⦵_{\text{cell}}= -0.44--2.37=\pu{+1.93V}\\
\end{align}$$

Both reactions are feasible, and I'd imagine the first would proceed until the concentration of $\ce {Fe^{3+} {(aq)}}$ is very low, and then the second would start at a noticeable rate.
This assumes, of course, the iron solid is able to deposit on the carbon cathode, and I don't see why not.

Hope this was helpful.

(Thank you Dr. J for pointing out my typo)

Comment: @Tamir-Did you mean to say that the first would proceed until the concentration of Fe3+ is very low, and then the second would start.  Or did you actually mean to say  Fe2+?

Comment: yes, my mistake, I'll edit it